# Who fulfills the logic?

Tags: cipher, pattern

Imagine you are on a spaceship. To activate this machine, you have to enter a code with these given clues.

**1110C17***42*

**0110F12***30*

**1001B11***26*

**--------------**

You have to enter the fourth code using one of the given codes. Which code suits the logic above?

1. **10110E27***33*
2. **11001Z51***146*
3. **1111A32***40*
4. **11011C30***36*

Hints:

1. > Simple addition and multiplication with 2
2. > 0100100101110010, what is it?
3. > What value does the slanted number holds?
4. > 64×1+8×2+3=83

Comment: Hint 2 when translated leads to rot13(ve). Hmmmmm

Comment: It is just a random binary code. I am just telling you that it is a binary code, it doesn't mean anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next code is

> `11001Z51146`

The pattern is

> `bin + A1Z26 = dec; dec * 2 = oct`
>  With the example of `1110C1742`:
>  1110<sub>2</sub> = 14<sub>10</sub>
>  C = 3
>  14 + 3 = 17
>  42<sub>8</sub> = 34<sub>10</sub> = 17 * 2
>
>  And with the answer, `11001Z51146`:
>  11001<sub>2</sub> = 25<sub>10</sub>
>  Z = 26
>  25 + 26 = 51
>  146<sub>8</sub> = 102<sub>10</sub> = 51 * 2

If this is the correct rule, the answer is the only possible one because

> The octal numbers of the of the other options do not equal x*2, but x